# Rudin's RCA Theorem 6.16: Uniform convergence of simple functions to $f\in L^\infty(\mu)$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

In the proof of Theorem 6.16 in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, I found a part that is a bit ambiguous for me. It says:

> > By Linearity it follows that
> >     \begin{equation*}
> > \Phi(f) = \int_Xfgd\mu
> > \end{equation*}
> >     holds for every simple measurable $f$, and so also for every $f\in L^\infty(\mu)$, since every $f\in L^\infty(\mu)$ is a uniform limit of simple functions $f_i$. Note that the uniform convergence of $f_i$ to $f$ implies $\|f_i - f\|_p\to0$, hence $\Phi(f_i)\to\Phi(f)$, as $i\to\infty$.

To prove that there exist simple measurable functions $f_i$ satisfying $\|f_i-f\|_p\to0$, I firstly let $f_0\in L^\infty(\mu)$ be a bounded function satisfying $\|f-f_0\|_\infty=0$ and then constructed simple measurable functions $f_i$ that uniformly converge to $f_0$ on $X$, thereby proving $\|f-f_i\|_p \to 0$ as $i\to\infty$. However, it only shows that $f_i$ uniformly converge to $f$ on a set $X - N$ with $\mu(N) = 0$ because $f$ is essentially bounded. So, my question is: Is there another way to construct simple measurable functions $f_i$ that uniformly converge to $f$ on $X$ or is it legitimate to say "uniformly converge to $f$" in this case?

Comment: So in your question, you do not just want $f_i \rightarrow f$ in $\| \cdot \|_{\infty}$ almost everywhere but actually converge in sup norm in the whole real line? In this case, $f$ could have a strictly increasing sequence in a countable set that has measure $0$. In this case, there might not be a sequence of simple functions converging to $f$ in sup norm.

Comment: @SanaeKochiya Thanks for your answer. Now, I am certain that "uniform convergence" actually means convergence in $L^\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construction is needed.

Since $f=f^{+}-f^{-}$, we can assume that $f\geq 0$.

For $0\leq f(x)\leq\|f\|_{L^{\infty}}:=M$ a.e. and hence the construction $f_{n}$ that
\begin{align*}
f_{n}(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{2^{n}}\dfrac{i-1}{2^{n}}\cdot M\chi_{f^{-1}\left(\dfrac{i-1}{2^{n}}\cdot M,\dfrac{i}{2^{n}}\cdot M\right]}
\end{align*}
is such that for $x\in f^{-1}\left(\dfrac{i-1}{2^{n}}\cdot M,\dfrac{i}{2^{n}}\cdot M\right]$ that
\begin{align*}
f_{n}(x)=\dfrac{i-1}{2^{n}}\cdot M<f(x)\leq\dfrac{i}{2^{n}}\cdot M,
\end{align*}
so 
\begin{align*}
0<(f-f_{n})(x)\leq\dfrac{M}{2^{n}},
\end{align*}
but the points do not lie inside $f^{-1}(0,M]$ are of measure zero, and hence
\begin{align*}
\|f-f_{n}\|_{L^{\infty}}\leq\dfrac{M}{2^{n}}\rightarrow 0
\end{align*}
as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but your construction of $f_n$ seems not also to guarantee $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $X$. Here, I understand uniform convergence as the convergnece of supremum norm of $f-f_n$. I guess that $\|f-f_n\|_\infty\to0$ is sufficient for the proof of Theorem 6.16. What bothers me is the sentence "every $f\in L^\infty(\mu)$ is a uniform limit of simple functions $f_i$".

Comment: Indeed it is not uniformly in the sense of everywhere controlled $\sup$. Take for example $f(x)=\infty$ for measure zero $x$, how is that simple functions being possible to do the job? Yes, $L^{\infty}$ norm is sufficient to complete the job in Rudin one.

Comment: Since $L^\infty(\mu)$ is defined as the set of all essentially bounded complex functions on $X$ in Rudin, $f(x) = \infty$ is not possible.

Comment: Okay, anyway, I don't see it must be possible for $\sup$.

Comment: As Sanae Kochiya commented above, if there is a divergent sequence $\{f(x_i)\}$, then I guess that there does not exist uniformly convergent simple functions. Then, I should understand that the uniform convergence actually means almost everywhere. Thanks for your answer again.